# conjugate space

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the coordinates

$\phi^\ast(\epsilon_{2}^\ast+\epsilon_{3}^\ast)$ in base $A^\ast$

where $A$ is $(3,4,5),(1,3,-2),(0,1,-2)$
and $M(\phi^\ast)_{st}^{st}=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 3 & 2 \\
        2 & -4 & 1 \\
        -3 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Could someone explain the exercie for me?